# How to grab numbers from chart in powerpoint with broken link to excel sheet

Tags: excel, charts, powerpoint, diagram

I have a Powerpoint file that has been emailed to me. It has a chart with selectable columns and labels, indicating that it's not just an image. When I try to edit the chart in order to extract the data, I get the message "The linked file is not available. To edit the link, click the File tab. Click the info tab, and then under Related Documents, click Edit Links to Files."

If i click Open Source, it says it can't find it. If I click Break Link, it's no longer editable when right clicking the table.

The data must be in there since it's displaying the values. How can I extract the data?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, what you see on screen is a metafile picture of the linked chart or other content. The data behind it is unavailable if the link's broken or missing. You may be able to get what you want by ungrouping the chart (or better, a copy of it). You'll probably need to ungroup a few times, but you should be able to access the text (as individual, unrelated text boxes).

Comment: The ungrouping item is greyed out. I read in another forum that I could copy and past as an "Enhanced Metafile". The only similar option when I CRTL+ALT+V however is "Picture (Enhanced Metafile)". This item is ungroupable, but only ungroups into data-less textboxes and rectangles corresponding to the original chart.

Comment: @Henrik Yes. That's what I suggested would happen ... it ungroups to individual text boxes, not data.

Comment: I see. I'm afraid that's not quite what I was looking for, as I still would have to (and indeed already did) extract the values manually. Thanks for the answer though!